# Does AudioTrack need to be assigned the same AudioSessionId as AudioRecord when using AcousticEchoCanceler?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm having trouble getting the AcousticEchoCanceler feature to work well (as in, actually subtract echo) on my Google Pixel 3a and in my setup. My setup consists of a phone (my Pixel, in this case) and a desktop computer that are networked together exchanging audio packets. The end goal is a two-way audio application. The two-way audio happens and works, but as I mentioned previously, there's echo.

I've searched SO, but I've found conflicting results on exactly what needs to be enabled/disabled and on how well things actually work even when they do.

By searching, I've found I need to enable InCommunication:

```
 AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
            am.Mode = Mode.InCommunication;
```

But it's not entirely clear whether AudioTrack and AudioRecord need to be tied together through the session ID, though in my case it doesn't *seem* to matter as I still get echo:

```
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.GetMinBufferSize(SampleRate,
                    ChannelIn.Mono,
                    Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit);


                AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(
                    AudioSource.VoiceCommunication,
                    //44100,
                    SampleRate,
                    ChannelIn.Mono,
                    Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,
                    bufferSize);

                if (EchoCancellationAvailable)
                {
                    AcousticEchoCanceler aec = AcousticEchoCanceler.Create(record.AudioSessionId);
                    if (!aec.Enabled)
                    {
                        aec.SetEnabled(true);
                    }
                }

                int numBytesToWrite = AudioTrack.GetMinBufferSize(SampleRate,
                    ChannelOut.Mono,
                    Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit);

                AudioTrack play = new AudioTrack(
                    Android.Media.Stream.Music,
                    //44100,
                    SampleRate,
                    ChannelOut.Mono,
                    Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,
                    numBytesToWrite,
                    AudioTrackMode.Stream, 
                    record.AudioSessionId);
```

I then use AudioRecord and AudioTrack in two separate threads. Did I associate the two objects together correctly? Do I need to? Are there any other issues that perhaps stand out as to why echo cancellation isn't really subtracting the echo?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you do not need to pass an Id into the AudioTrack ctor, use the other ctor (note: if you are targeting API21+ use the `Builder` instead of the deprecated ctors.) Also why are you using two threads? One thread (runnable) where you read from AudioRecord and pass the buffer to AudioTrack is all you need. Also AcousticEchoCanceler should be a class level var so you do not leak memory on C#/Java peer member and cause a fault. Also this only works for echo on the device itself, i.e. the mic to the speaker (not sure if your picking up your desktop audio output back on the phone's mic)

Comment: AudioRecord is taking audio data from the microphone and sending it to the desktop machine via the network; AudioTrack is taking the audio data from the desktop machine over the network and playing it on the device's speaker. What I'm hearing is my voice from the speaker of the other device. I thought the idea of AEC was to identify  the wave properties of my voice and remove it from that which comes out of the speaker on the device, including the echo from the other side.

Comment: `..including the echo from the other side.` If the "echo" is generated by the device's mic picking up the audio from a speaker output of your desktop, then no, as the phase of that will not match the original source to what you are receiving back and playing via AudioTrack, i.e. a secondary source feeding/mixing into the AudioRecord source would be an double(+) echo, i.e. feedback, AEC would not help much. So is it the original echo, or secondary echo (feedback)? On some devices, feedback/oscillation can be suppressed by adding noise suppression w/ AEC at the same time (`NoiseSuppressor`)

Comment: They're in separate rooms, so the "device" (the phone in the case, I believe is what you mean) cannot hear the other machine's speaker. What's happening is the output from the speaker of the machine in the other room is being picked up by its own mic (there's no echo cancellation on it), and sent back to the phone over the network. I was under the impression AEC was aware of the phase it sent via microphone and removed that from what came out its own speakers. Do I have the concept backwards or something?

Comment: @Ben have you solved your problem?